# How to bookmark the last track in Windows Media Player?

Tags: bookmarks, windows-media-player

I listen to audiobooks. When I close my laptop and subsequently reboot, I need to spend time to find where I was in the audiobook. Is there a way to bookmark my last track?

Please don't offer suggestions for other software, like iTunes; I am used to Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MyMediaBookmarks](http://www.catenalogic.com/products/mymediabookmarks/information) can do this for you, it was built with this idea in mind.

> Always watching videos with Windows
>   Media Player and have to leave in the
>   middle? Then you need to remember the
>   position of the movie and continue
>   later.
>
> The same for audio! Are you in the
>   middle of a great mix and you need to
>   leave in the middle? Don't bother
>   searching the last position any
>   longer. Let MyMediaBookmarks do this
>   for you!
>
> MyMediaBookmarks is a Windows Media
>   Player (WMP) plug-in which allows you
>   to create bookmarks for audio and
>   video files. This free, easy to use
>   plug-in can automatically create
>   bookmarks and continue audio and video
>   files. This way, you don't have to
>   keep remembering the position of the
>   media and seek to that position when
>   media is interrupted.

The supported operating systems are Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista and Windows CE. It doesn't list the versions of WMP compatible, but I assume they indicate it is compatible with the default version shipped with these versions of Windows.

MyMediaBookmarks is freeware.